# Russian plural for jQuery countdown widget for Yii2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I used for my web app this [widget](https://github.com/russ666/yii2-countdown) but I encountered an issue:

[image]

As I read in official docs, I can only implement this format config

```
'format' => '%-D %!D:день,дней; %H:%M:%S',
```

But how can I set new plural rules ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is no such possibility in this lib, but you can rewrite function *pluralize* in [countdown.js](https://github.com/hilios/jQuery.countdown/blob/master/dist/jquery.countdown.js) like this:

```
function pluralize(format, count) {
    var plural = "s", singular = "", plural_2_4 = "s";
    if (format) {
        format = format.replace(/(:|;|\s)/gi, "").split(/\,/);
        if (format.length === 1) {
            plural = format[0];
            plural_2_4 = format[0];
        } else if (format.length === 2){
            singular = format[0];
            plural = format[1];
            plural_2_4 = format[1];
        } else {
            singular = format[0];
            plural_2_4 = format[1];
            plural = format[2];
        }
    }
    if (Math.abs(count) % 10 === 1) {
        return singular;
    } else if (Math.abs(count) % 10 > 1 && Math.abs(count) % 10 < 5) {
        return plural_2_4;
    } else {
        return plural;
    }
}
```

I just added one more break point for Russian grammar. Now, using *%!d:день, дня, дней;* you will get *день* for 1, *дня* for 2 - 4 and *дней* for all the rest including 0. Hope this helps.